# Obter objetos de uma lista, filtrados por DateTime em C#

Tags: c#

Possuo uma lista de objetos, da qual precido filtrar e obter todos os objetos cadastrados anteriormente ao mês atual, ou seja, os objetos do mês anterior para trás. Por exemplo: estamos no mês janeiro, sendo assim, eu preciso extrair todos os objetos cadastrados até o mês de dezembro, inclusive. Estou utilizando o seguinte código, no entanto, ele considera os objetos cadastrados no mês corrente, já que os dias no DateTime permitem isso.

```
List<Operacao> operacoesAnteriores = operacoes.Where(o => o.Data < DateTime.Now).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Como voce mesmo mencionou, dessa forma `.Where(o => o.Data < DateTime.Now)` será selecionado todas as datas que forem anteriores ao dia atual.

Para você selecionar as datas do mês anterior, ao invés de você comparar com a data atual, você cria um novo `DateTime` referente ao primeiro dia do mês atual.

```
new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 01)
```

No seu caso ficaria

```
List<Operacao> operacoesAnteriores = operacoes.Where(o => o.Data < new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 01)).ToList();
```